# Filter long log parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I allow users to upload files on my site. And some of those files can be very large and it eats up a huge chunk of my log files. So I would like to not have it show up. I know about:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

To filter certain parameters. But the problem with this is that it the parameter is in a hash like this:

```
{
   :person => { 
      :name => 'bob', 
      :file => { 
         :data => 'really long data. this can be tens of thousands of characters long' 
      }
   }
}
```

I could add :data to the filter_parameters but that would hiding lots of logs across the whole site since data is a common key (I also can't rename this to something more obscure). Is it possible for filter_parameters to take in a nested parameter? Or is there another way to limit the length of all parameters so if they come in bigger than a certain size, it would not be stored in my log files.

Comment: Why would uploading a large file use up a lot of log? It should be a single entry saying it was uploaded.

Comment: I guess I should've worded this better. It's not coming from my own website. Another website is posting it through a route on my site. It comes along with lots of other attributes and a file is one of the many things it's sending me.

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you showed a minimal example of the file so we can see it, not try to imagine it.

Comment: I updated it a bit if it helps. But basically there is this really long params that can be tens of thousands of lines long because of a large file. And it's killing my logs

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? trying to find the same. In my case, the `:data` is an image as base64 text.

Comment: I couldn't find a really good way to do this but I I hacked around it. I posted the answer below. Hopefully it can help you or maybe you can find a better way to do this.

Comment: I think this is fairly normal thing to want to do. I work daily with REST APIs that accept base64 strings for files and the logs get impossible to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up putting something like this in my application.rb

```
config.filter_parameters << lambda do |k, v|
  if k == 'data' && v && v.class == String && v.length > 1024
    v.replace('[FILTER]')
  end
end
```

I couldn't find a better way to do this. So I look for the key 'data' in the params. And if the value for that data is a String and over a certain length, I just replace it so the logs isn't so cluttered.

Answer (score 2):

Since Rails 5.0, [`filter_parameters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html) supports filtering for nested parameters using a dot notation.

In this case it would be:

```
config.filter_parameters += ['person.file.data']
```

There is an example in the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html) and at the `actionpack` [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md):

> Add ability to filter parameters based on parent keys.
>
> ```
> # matches {credit_card: {code: "xxxx"}}
> # doesn't match {file: { code: "xxxx"}}
> config.filter_parameters += [ "credit_card.code" ]
> ```
>
> See [#13897](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13897).